# how to execute the rails application in rails 2.3.14?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to the rails programming. I was building my first rails application.

In internet I was searched how to run the rails application in rails 2.3.14 version. But I did not get the answer.

I know how to start the server. But I don't know how run the rails application.

Can anyone please explain me how to run the rails application in 2.3.14 version.

Comment: Interesting... It is very strange that you are trying to use rails 2 for non legacy project. It was released 5 years ago.

Comment: @PavelTkackenko To refer old projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start a server in Rails 2.3 with:

```
./script/server start
```

That starts a local server in `development` mode, browse to `http://localhost:3000` to see your application.

You might want to have a look at the other scripts in the `scripts` folder too, you will find a subset of modern `rails` commands. Like

```
./script/console
```

to open the Rails console.

But I wouldn't recommend to learn Rails with a 2.3 application. 2.3 has many differences to modern Rails 4.2 or 5.0 application.

Comment: The ./script/console gives the console window. My need is, I have a html files and controller scripts under the app directory. The controller script is placed in controller directory and the html file is placed under view/layout directory. I need to execute that whole application. It needs to open the browser window. But in here it gives just console.

Comment: Start the server with `./script/server start` and view that page with a bowser at `http://localhost:3000/` (plus your route like configured in `routes.rb`).